# ASP.Net MVC web application Impersonated doesn't react the same way out of the server

Tags: web-services, asp.net-mvc-5, odata, impersonation, iis-8.5

I have developed an asp.net mvc 5 web application that works with impersonation. I'm using Impersonation because my web app is calling Navision Dynamics web services and I don't want the users to enter the credentials.

I have deployed my web application on a Windows Server 2012 R2 with IIS 8.5. 
I have changed the application pool to .NET 4.5 Classic with a Classic Pipeline mode and I have activated the impersonation authentication.

My web application works well while I navigate it form the Server Internet Explorer but raise me an “System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceClientException: Forbidden” error when I try to access it from another computer.
If I stay on the server and change localhost to myServerName in the URL, I don't get any error but I don't receive my data from Navision.

Here is my System web configuration

```
<system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <identity impersonate="true" />
</system.web>
```

Here is the way I Consume My Navision Service

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Web;

namespace MyWebApplication.Models
{
    public class Matter
    {
        public string Matter_No { get; set; }
        public string Matter_Label { get; set; }
    }

    public static class MatterDataContext
    {
        [OperationBehavior(Impersonation = ImpersonationOption.Required)]
        public static IEnumerable<Matter> GetMatters()
        {
            List<Matter> matterLines = new List<Matter>();

            Uri uri = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NavisionODataUri"]);
            var NAV = new NavServiceRef.NAV(uri);
            NAV.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

            var resultMatterLines = from m in NAV.matterlist
                                    select m;

            foreach (var m in resultMatterLines)
            {
                Matter ligne = new Matter();

                ligne.Matter_No = m.Matter_No;
                ligne.Matter_Label = m.Matter_Label;
                matterLines.Add(ligne);
            }

            return matterLines;
        }
    }
}
```

I have added  this peace of code to my index for debug

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>Application code executed using</td>
        <td>@System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Is user authenticated</td>
        <td>@User.Identity.IsAuthenticated</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Authentication type, if authenticated</td>
        <td>@User.Identity.AuthenticationType</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>User name, if authenticated</td>
        <td>@User.Identity.Name</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and I receive what I was expecting :

Application code executed using:       DOMAIN\jeremy 
Is user authenticated:                 True 
Authentication type, if authenticated: NTLM 
User name, if authenticated:           DOMAIN\jeremy

I can't find what I'm doing wrong...
Can someone help me please?

Comment: When I look at my server's logs it says that I don't use Impersonation...

Comment: If I deploy my web app on my Navision server it works but it is not an option

Comment: Using an SSL certificat doesn't change anything neither

Answer (score 1):

you need to do the following : 
 - verify that you installed both 
          ASP.NET and windows authentication on IIS 
 - once installed  , from IIS authentication verify that you enabled windows Authentication and impersonation and disabled anonymous access